# Access report : conditional formating on a pivot table or report

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

I've that data in access 2010

```
Key    Value Sec Rank Statut
142    71   AG  3    1
140    69   AG  1    1
141    70   AG  2    2
84     32   BK  1    2
96     40   BK  2    2
```

I need to generate a report like

```
Value Rank1 Rank2 Rank3
AG    69    70    71
BK    32    40
```

(the header column is the rank, the header row give the Sec, and the detail give the value)

I tryied to use the pivot table but I can't apply conditionnal formating. (otherwise it would be a great solution)
I need to chance the background color if the statut = 1.

I think I have to have a query that show for each column one rank

for example :

```
Sec Rank1 Rank2 Rank3 Rank1Statut Rank2Statut Rank3statut
AG    69    70    71  1           2           1
BK    32    40        2           2
```

but i didn't manage to reproduce that
do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than one query. For example:

Rank

```
TRANSFORM Min(t.Value) AS MinOfValue
SELECT t.Sec
FROM ATable t
GROUP BY t.Sec
PIVOT t.Rank
```

Statut

```
TRANSFORM Min(t.Statut) AS MinOfStatut
SELECT t.Sec
FROM ATable t
GROUP BY t.Sec
PIVOT t.Rank
```

Joining both

```
SELECT Rank.Sec, Rank.[1], Rank.[2], Rank.[3], 
       Statut.[1], Statut.[2], Statut.[3]
FROM Rank INNER JOIN Statut ON Rank.Sec = Statut.Sec;
```